# How to make Excel sheet readonly using asp.net?

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

My Task is to generate excel sheet as read only(i e., columns data should not be editable) using asp.net? 
I am getting data from the database,then am generating the excel sheet for that data but it is editable.I want to make my excel sheet as non editable.
How should I do?
Anybody can please help me?

I have written code like this..

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Where is your code? Asp.net has nothing to do with your task, next time please specify C# or VB.NET tags, as your task has to be implemented by language code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look this topic - [first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.readonly%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [second](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/f89fe6b3-68c0-4a98-9522-953cc5befb34). Second one offers a solution even for cells.